# How to find all the data on a box-and-whisker plot? Most importantly the mean

Tags: algorithms, boxplot

I am super stuck on the question. I looked up on how to find the mean on a Box-and-whisker plot, and never got a clear answer.
[image: This is the question I am seeking an answer for]

Comment: Do the dots represent data points? You typically can't compute the mean from the box and whiskers themselves, but it's trivial if you have all the data points.

Comment: If there are only five values, then the mean of $43,58,82,93,117$ is lower than the median of $82$ so presumably you are supposed to say False.

Comment: This question seems to be predicated on an unusual meaning of "box and whisker plot" in which its waistline locates the mean rather than the median.  Or perhaps there is a typo in the question where "mean" is intended to read "median."